# Linear Algebra - Determinant Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

A = \begin{bmatrix}
       a & b & c           \\[0.3em]
       d & e & f           \\[0.3em]
       g & h & i           
     \end{bmatrix}
B = \begin{bmatrix}
       g & h & i            \\[0.3em]
       a & b & c           \\[0.3em]
       2d & 2e & 2f           
     \end{bmatrix},

If det(B) = $6$, What is det(A)?
First, I obtained A by:
 1) $R_{1}$ <-> $R_{3}$
 2) $R_{2}$ <-> $R_{3}$
 3) $2R_{2}$.
Then, by using determinant properties I got that det(A) = 12. 
I am not too sure if I am using the determinant properties correctly to obtain det(A).

Comment: You're wrong for  $\det A$: you have $\det B=2\det A$, so $\,\det A=3$. You might simplify  the explanation about the permutations  of rows considering the cycle $\,(123)$, which is an even permutation, hence it doesn't change the sign of the determinant.

Comment: @Bernard I dont understand why det(A) = 3, interchanging rows changes sign of the determinant right ? so I got : 
det(A) = -det(B) R1 <-> R3,
          = det(B)   R2 <-> R3,
          = 2det(B) = (2)(6)  2R2

Comment: Fot the sign, it's OK, I only was suggesting a shortest way to explain using the signature of the global permutation, but that's unessential. But ging from A to B consists in multiplying a row by $2$, hence the determinant is also multiplied by $2$ (by linearity): this means $\det B=2\det A$, not the converse.